# AngularJS watchers: oldValue equal to newValue in unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I met an issue with AngularJS watchers in unit test.

When running the app, it is working as expected but in unit test, oldValue is always equal to newValue which led to failing test when testing inequality between these values in watchers (which is common I think).

I've made a little plunkr to illustrate that: http://plnkr.co/edit/a5er4f?p=preview
Take a look at the console to observe the behavior. 
In index.html, normal mode, everything is fine, oldValue is always different of newValue.
In Jasmine reporter, they are always equal.

Any thoughts about this? Maybe I'm doing something wrong in my test?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things are going on:

First: You are instantiating your controller in your test appSpec.js using $controller, which is correct. However, you are *also* instantiating a controller with jasmine-reporter.html using `<body ng-controller="WatchCtrl">` The two watchers are probably screwing up your test. Remove that, and while you're at it, remove the ng-app="testApp" from the html tag. You take care of initializing your app with angular.mock.module.

Second: $watch is triggered during initialization with `newVal == oldVal == null`. See the documentation for $watch here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope. So you should expect one $watch loop where newVal = oldVal per controller instantiation.

Also note that you aren't seeing the output when you change aValue in your test because when running as a test, `$log` has been mocked out. You can switch to using `console.log` to see messages from the test.

Plnkr with changes made: http://plnkr.co/edit/voPQax?p=preview

Comment: Hi Jmr, thanks a lot for your lights. Seems that you haven't save your Plnkr, it is still the same than the original. 
About the double declaration, sorry about that, you're right but I am able to reproduce this without HTML in plain Jasmine test runned by Karma. Also, what is the correct way to instantiate controller in tests? I've always seen this way, cf. the official doc: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller

Comment: Plunkr has been saved (the changes are mostly in jasmine-reporter.html)

Comment: You're instantiating the controller the correct way using the $controller service in beforeEach().

Comment: Sorry I've read "incorrect". I've updated mine too with expected output (in appspec) please tell me if I'm wrong. I'll take a look to yours

Comment: Just add another `scope.$digest()` before you change `scope.aValue` to test. Then it will initialize with `null` instead of initializing with `test`. Edited plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/a9TO5s?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `$scope.$apply()` manually in the tests for the watchers to fire otherwise they would not check the value changes, remaining the same.

Comment: he is calling $scope.$digest() so $scope.$apply() is not required

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've actually tried both but as Ajay said, $diggest should be enough